# AWS Server-less Architecture using Lambda and SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-serverless

I've been learning more and more about AWS lately. I've been reading through the white papers and working my way through the various services. I've been working on PHP applications and front-end dev for a while now. Two things really stuck out to me. Those two things are server-less architecture using Lambdas with event-triggers and SQS (queues). The last three years I have been working with REST over HTTP with frameworks like Angular.

It occurred to me though that one could create an entire back-end/service layer through Lambda's and message queues alone. Perhaps I'm naive as I have never used that type of architecture for a real world project but it seems like a very simple means to build a service layer.

Has anyone built a web application back-end consisting of only Lambdas and message queues as opposed to "traditional" http request with REST. If so what types of drawbacks are there to this type of architecture besides relying so heavily on a vendor like AWS?

For example, wouldn't it be entirely possible to build a CMS using these technologies where the scripts create the AWS assets programmatically given a key with full admin rights to an account?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can practically create the entire backend service using serverless architecture.

There are a lot of AWS services that usually play into the serverless gambit of things. 
DynamoDB, SNS, SQS, S3 to name a few.
AWS Lambda is the backbone and sort of acts as a glue to bind these services.

Serverless doesn't mean you move away from "traditional" http request to message queues. If you need the web interface you would still need to use HTTP. You would primarily use message queues to decouple your services.

So, if you want the service to be accessible over HTTP just like your REST services and still be serverless then you can do that as well. And for that you will need to use AWS API Gateway in conjunction with AWS Lambda

One primary drawback/limitation is that debugging is not very straightforward. You cannot login to the system and cannot attach remote debuggers. And then obviously you get tied into the vendor.

Then there are limitations on the resources. E.g. Lambda can offer you a maximum memory footprint of 5GB, so if you need to do some compute intensive job that needs more memory and can't be broken down into sub tasks then serverless (AWS Lambda) is not an option for you.

Comment: When reading about this I immediately thought about how dfficult it would be to debug and develop in a team of people. Aws servrrless and stateless architecture sounds awesome but not being able to do local dev and smart debug is a huge downer.